# 2D Array Method Text Formatting

Tags: java, arrays, format

I'm new to Java and recently learned how to use loops and array.
It took me quite a while but now I got the numbers in the right index and print orders. My only issue is that it's printing without aligning to each other. (like in a table - row/column)

I found out about

```
System.out.format("%-4d", table[t][i]);
```

of "Roby Cornelissen" on stackoverflow, but since I need a return and on top of that don't use the array but a variable, I'm out of ideas. String.format didn't seem to work for me either, or I used it wrong.

Here is my method:

```
    public String generateBoard(){
        int total = board.length * board[0].length;
        int zaehler = 0;
        String line = "<html>";
            for( int row = 0; row < board.length; row++){
                zaehler = ( total + 1 ) - ( (row + 1 ) * board[row].length );
                for  ( int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++){
                    board[row][col] = zaehler++;
                    line = line + board[row][col] + " ";
                }
                line = line + "<br>";
            }
        line = line + "</html>";
        return (line);

}
```

I appreciate every help / tips.

Comment: please provide current output and expected output (tip, you can use the code format to format properly)

Comment: Multiline String are hard to align, you can use `format` like you said, the format depends on the type of value. But this is limited (if a value is longer, it will break the alignment or you will need to truncate the value).

Comment: You seem to be using HTML. In that case, you should probably display a table as an HTML `<table>`. Alignment methods based on spaces will not work in a browser (except in `<PRE>` tags, which really shouldn't be used for this), because browsers convert all consecutive whitespaces into a single space.